# How to Display Wiki Page in HTML using React

Tags: reactjs

so my goal is to display a Page from Wikipedia in my Web-Page using React. I have only one Idea to do that, and it's:

- **First** Step: Export data from Wiki as .XML
- **Second** Step: import data from .xml in HTML(using React).

First Step I have done succesfully, but I have Problems with second.

I have found xml-parser from npm(xml-loader):https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-loader. but it's giving me only following string: "**/static/media/wiki.c6730c07.xml**" . Knows someone better way to do that, or it will be good if you say, that I am on right way. My code in React is :

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import logo from './logo.svg';
import './App.css';
var wiki = require('./wiki.xml');

class App extends Component {

  render() {

    return (
      <div className="App">
        {wiki}
      </div>
    );
  }
}

export default App;
```

Comment: according to the xml-loader package documentation, you should add `xml!` at the start of your file to tell the parser to take over. `var wiki = require('xml!./wiki.xml');`

Comment: I did that, but console had gaved me Error: "Unexpected '!' in 'xml!./wiki.xml'. Do not use import syntax to configure webpack loaders  import/no-webpack-loader-syntax"

Comment: than, I have editied Code in webpack config(it's written on website) and now I am here "/static/media/wiki.c6730c07.xml" "

Comment: that is an ESlint error. You can ignore it by adding `/* eslint import/no-webpack-loader-syntax: "off" */` at the top of the component file.

Comment: I have such  eslint Folder as : 'eslint-config-react-app', 'eslint', 'eslint-loader'.... . In which of them I have to edit it ?

Comment: You need to add it to the component file that does the `require`

Comment: I didi as you sad, but now I am getting following Error: "Module not found: Can't resolve 'xml' in 'C:\Users\..\Projekts\display-wiki\src'" .   xml file is in same Folder as App(both of them are in src). I have moved it in public Folder but now I get this Error: "Module not found: You attempted to import /wiki.xml which falls outside of the project src/ directory. Relative imports outside of src/ are not supported."

Answer (score 0):

[xml-renderer](https://www.npmjs.com/package/xml-renderer) might be a good candidate for helping you.

Answer (score 0):

So, I have found out that, to do something like this, I have to use "xslt", where I can get data from ".xml" and display them how I want. Important is to create a reference between xml and xslt. Here are tree links, where you can see it on example:

1. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Zn9A5k23Oto
2. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Icg0Su5uEa8
3. https://www.codeproject.com/Articles/12047/How-to-Convert-XML-Files-to-HTML

But last question is: I want to display data from Wiki exactly how it is on it's Page, Is this Possible ?

If someone knows answer, please write Hint.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding to your second question, about how to display data from Wiki exactly how it is on it's Page, you can use the `<iframe>` tag.
You can find [more information here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/iframe).